# Windows 7 Start Menu Dividers

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

Is it possible to put dividers in the Windows 7 start menu? If so, how?

I'd like to put dividers in the same location as the red line.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to regain the control over the Start menu which was available in previous versions of Windows before 7, is to use an alternative third-party product. Most of them can either replace or run side-by-side with the original Windows one.

[CSMenu](http://www.csmenu.com/) (free), discussed in detail in this [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2227/get-the-classic-start-menu-in-windows-7/).

> CSMenu is a little application which
>   acts like the classic start menu. It's
>   designed for Windows 7, which doesn't
>   have a classic start menu.

[Start Menu 7](http://www.startmenu7.com/index.html) (free, Pro version $19.99)

[Aston Menu](http://www.aston2menu.com/) ($19.95)

[Start Menu Organizer](http://www.winstep.net/startmenuorganizer.asp) (free, Pro version $19.95)

Not all the products answer exactly your question of the separators, but they certainly allow organizing the Start menu in more ways than does Microsoft.

Answer (score 4):

The only divider possible is the one that splits the lower dynamic program listing from the upper items pinned to the start menu.

Right click one of the top apps you highlighted, select 'Pin to Start Menu' and it will be automatically placed above a divider line.

Answer (score 0):

This is not too bad of an alternative:
Create a desktop shortcut to C: or whatever.
Name it "______________"  (you decide on the length)
Drag this new desktop shortcut to your start menu at the desired position
Voila!
Yes you have an annoying graphic in front but that's life post XP!  (those bastards)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what this might look like please

Answer (score 0):

Create a new text file named -------------------------.txt

Create a shortcut and pin it to start menu.

If more than one separator is needed, name the txt files like this:

```
-------------------------.txt
------------------------.txt
-----------------------.txt
```

...etc

The varying lengths shouldn't be that noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Similar, but slightly better than @Fixer1234's answer:  Create the text files, but then you can rename them so they have no ".txt" extension and you will only see the dashes.  You just have to remember you can't have 2 files with the same name, so make them all have a different number of dashes.

[image: See example screenshot]

For Win7, this is the folder I put them into:

```
%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
```