# Stardock's Start8+10+11 - horizontal line separators in the Windows 7 and Modern Style start menus

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8, windows-11

What causes Windows to a show a horizontal additional line separator(it appears above the same type of line divider that acts as a border before the sub menu *All Programs*) on the Windows 7 start menu and where is Windows regulating this exactly?
I know that there can be the case that there is no such a line visible and if there is one available - that there is definitely a way to trigger that this additional line divider would totally disappear from the start menu again, since I was definitely able to achieve this several times in the past - I can't remember what I did exactly though. This would probably also apply to later Windows versions with specific Software installed(for example Start10/11) that offers Windows 7 start menu skins with customization options.

[image]

Comment: There are some suggestions in https://superuser.com/q/253544/309436

Comment: The goal of my topic is at the first place to find out again how to remove this specific divider I mentioned.

Comment: maybe all user / current user seperation?

Comment: Come to think about it, I don't think I've ever seen separators in W7, 8 or 10 other than on the context menu.  On the context menu, the separator is set in the registry.  If you search for **CommandFlags dword 20**, there are quite a few hits on how to do this.

Comment: The horizontal lines are a UI element that can be removed or modified in Windows ≤8.1, possibly w/ Windows 7 Style Start Menu UIs in Windows 10/11. In Windows ≤8.1, this, and every other element of the [Windows Shell](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell) UI can be modified via [Stardock Windowblinds](https://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/)' SkinStudio _(it's bundled with WindowBlinds, with the element modified within Photoshop)_, whereas if it is possible in Windows 10/11, it would likely only be possible with Windows 7 Style UIs set via programs like Stardock's Start10/Start11

Comment: I see. In this context I discovered a bug in Stardock's Start10/8 - 11? that I could always reproduce with installations of different Windows 10 Pro (and my old Win 8)  licenses. It has no negative effect otherwise: If you click rapidly on any adjustable option - for example in Configure section or somewhere else in the program - this will at some point trigger the event that this specific design element(separator line) would permanently disappear from the Windows 7 and Modern Style start menus.